# React/CSS transform: translate() transition puts some elements out of place for the duration of the transition

Tags: css, reactjs

When moving all elements inside a flexbox with transform: translate() some elements appear out of place during the transition and then snap in place. I counted that the first element this problem appears is the 13th.

UPDATE: What I've figured out so far is that this problem occurs on Chrome and Edge. But on Firefox it works just as intended. I've also simplified the code so I will change the code that was previously here a bit. Also the problem appears to get worse the further the items are offset with transform.

UPDATE: The problem appears to be caused by the recalculation of the images size/position. When I added overflow: hidden to the images the problem disappeared. No idea why that worked...

React code:

```
        <div
          key={index}
          className="item-container"
          tabIndex={active ? 0 : undefined}
          style={{
            transform: `${activeItem < itemRefs.current.length - 4 ? `translateX(-${activeItem * 100}%)` : undefined}`,
            
          }}
          ref={(ref) => (itemRefs.current[index] = ref)}
        >
          <img src={url}/>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.item-carousel {
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.item-container{
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}
```

item-carousel is the main flexbox that contains all the items I move and item-container is for the individual items.

[An item out of place during transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQfOp.jpg)

I've tried removing almost all of the contents of the CSS file. Only keeping item-carousel as is, but the problem still occurs so I don't think that's where the problem is.

Comment: I think you should replace `padding: 5px` from `.item-container` to `.item-carousel`

Comment: padding: 5px is in correct location. I have box-sizing: border-box. Making the calculation of width based on both padding and the actual width of the element. That way when I translate 100% it will move exactly the width of the element + any spacing I want between them with padding.

Answer (score 0):

nice to use framer-motion for layout animation.

otherwise you should provide a minimal reproduce env